# Pool.imap_unordered skips value from the iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to run the following code to parallalize a function that crops geotifs. Geotifs are named as `<location>__img_news1a_iw_rt30_<hex_code>_g_gpf_vv.tif`. The code works perfectly fine but it skips a particular set of geotif from even reading from the vv_tif iterable. In particular, out of `locationA_img_news1a_iw_rt30_20170314t115609_g_gpf_vv.tif`, `locationA_img_news1a_iw_rt30_20170606t115613_g_gpf_vv.tif` and `locationA_img_news1a_iw_rt30_20170712t115615_g_gpf_vv.tif` it skips `locationA_img_news1a_iw_rt30_20170712t115615_g_gpf_vv.tif` every single time from reading when I read these files along with other location geotifs. However, it reads this file if I create an iterable from only these three geotif files. I have tried changing chunksize but it doesn't help. Am I missing something here?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
try:
    pool = Pool(cpu_count())
    pool.imap_unordered(tile_geotif, vv_tif, chunksize=11)
finally:
    pool.close()
```

EDIT: I have 55 files in total and it only drops `locationA_img_news1a_iw_rt30_20170712t115615_g_gpf_vv.tif` file every single time.

Comment: Tangential: you might want to use `with Pool(cpu_count()) as pool:` to replace `pool = Pool(cpu_count())` and then you can do away with the `try..finally` scaffolding and still be guaranteed that pool resources will be cleaned up.

Comment: I know that but thanks.

Comment: You don't show how you wait for all the results.  Are you calling `join` to allow all the children to finish?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest running out the iterator it produces, as unsubmitted tasks might be dropped when you `close` the pool. A simple `for _ in pool.imap_unordered(tile_geotif, vv_tif, chunksize=11): pass` would do the trick. Or as a true single expression approach, `collections.deque(pool.imap_unordered(tile_geotif, vv_tif, chunksize=11), 0)` (the most efficient way to consume an iterator without storing the results).

Comment: @TimRoberts I don't need a `join` since there is nothing to join. I am just parallelizing a for loop here.

Comment: @ShadowRanger It didn't help. Still pool process skipping that file.

Comment: @ShadowRanger `vv_tif` is an iterator won't running it in a `for` loop make it read multiple times?

Comment: Could you `print(vv_tif)` before and after the `imap_unordered` and confirm to us that indeed every element is in there?  We are scratching our heads on the assumption that your generator is producing correct data.  But we cannot confirm because we do not have a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I'm going to post an answer to share some code.

Comment: @RazzleShazl it doesn't have that file. I tried putting a print statement for every file that 's being read in the `tile_geotif ` function but out of 55 files it only misses that file.

Comment: Yes, you do need join.  Remember, when your main program exits, all the child processes are killed, whether they are finished or not.  Unless you are WAITING for the last process to finish, it's going to get an early termination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too much to show in comments, putting here in answer.

It seems to me that the map functions work in my toy examples below.  I think you have error in your input data to cause the corrupted output.  Either that, or you found a bug.  If so, do try to create a reproducible example.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

vv_tif = list(range(10))
def square(x):
    return x**x

with Pool(5) as p:
    print(p.map(square, vv_tif))

with Pool(5) as p:
    print(list(p.imap(square, vv_tif)))

with Pool(5) as p:
    print(list(p.imap_unordered(square, vv_tif)))

with Pool(5) as p:
    print(list(p.imap_unordered(square, vv_tif, chunksize=11)))
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 4, 27, 256, 3125, 46656, 823543, 16777216, 387420489]
[1, 1, 4, 27, 256, 3125, 46656, 823543, 16777216, 387420489]
[1, 1, 256, 3125, 46656, 823543, 16777216, 4, 27, 387420489]
[1, 1, 4, 27, 256, 3125, 46656, 823543, 16777216, 387420489]
```

Usually all 4 lines were the same.  I ran it a few times till I got a different ordering on one.  It looks to me that it works.

Note that his demonstrates that the various `map` functions are not mutating underlying data.

Comment: Is it possible that reading files is causing some issues?

Comment: @Coddy I tried `x/0` in my `square` function and sure enough the `ZeroDivisionError` crashed my program so either no errors are being thrown for your situation, or some code is catching and squashing that error.  You have no issue accessing the file with different code, so that tells me your OS has no problem accessing that file.  Perhaps the file is being generated *during* your program, and because you have a lock on it still, it can't be read?  Spitballing.

Comment: Simplifying like this helped me figure out the problem. I returned the file names instead of square and figured that there was a tricky bug I wasn't able to catch. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please notice the difference in results depending on whether the "time.sleep" is in or out.

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

def process(x):
    print(x)

def main():
    pool = Pool(4)
    pool.imap_unordered(process, (1,2,3,4,5))
    pool.close()
    #time.sleep(3)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```